# Derivation of Fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus

(lower bounds of definite integral is $x$ and upper bound is $x + \triangle x$ and the integrand is $f(u)$)). What I need help understanding is when you take the limit as $\triangle x \rightarrow 0$. It's clear that the LHS becomes $\frac{dF}{dx}$, however when you apply the same lim to the RHS is when i get confused. Doesnt $\frac{1}{\triangle x}$ approach infinity? I can somewhat make sense of what happens in the integral, as $\triangle x \rightarrow 0$ the upper bound basically becomes $x$. Thats all I can really make of it. Please explain what happens when you apply the $lim_{\triangle x \rightarrow 0}$ to the RHS. If possible intuitive answer. Thanks.

[image: Fundamental theorem of calulus]

Comment: What is the integral $\int_x^{x+\Delta x} f(x) du$?

Comment: @JensSchwaiger integrand is f(u)

Comment: No, I mean, what I wrote. This integral 
equals $f(x) \Delta x$

Answer (score 1):

The right-hand side is the product of two functions of $\Delta x$: the reciprocal $1/\Delta x$, and the integral with $\Delta x$ in the upper endpoint. Individually, the first function goes to $\infty$ in absolute value as $\Delta x\to0$, while the second function goes to $0$ as $\Delta x\to0$. Therefore their product is a "$\infty\cdot0$ indeterminate form": it's not immediately clear what the limit of the product is as $\Delta x\to0$ (but this doesn't contradict either of the individual limits). The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells us that the limit turns out to be $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $\Delta x$ goes to zero.

The RHS computes the average value of $f$ in a small interval. And when the interval shrinks, the average just tends to the local function value.